# Getdate() returning same value at different times! What is happening?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL run against a table with 1 million records is giving the same value for columns Date1 and Date2, and it took 38 seconds to execute. Is this an expected behavior and why?

```
CREATE FUNCTION Fn_Test(@a decimal)RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT @a Parameter, Getdate() Date1, PartitionTest.*
    FROM PartitionTest
);

SELECT *, GETDATE() Date2 FROM Fn_Test(RAND(DATEPART(s,GETDATE())))
```

Is this some kind of caching?

Comment: which version of sql server did you find this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. SQL semantics do no require that a non-deterministic function that *does not depend* on the current row to be evaluated *for each row*. It is allowed to evaluate the function once and return the same value for all subsequent rows.

Comment: In effect calling getdate in combination with a 'real' select simply bloats the resultset

Comment: Can you check this question too [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819513/big-performance-difference-1hr-to-1-minute-found-in-sql-can-you-explain-why]

Comment: And what can be done if we need the time at which a particular row was fetched?

Comment: You can't get the time a particular row was 'fetched' because that contradict the fundamental relational algebra that powers SQL as a language. You describe the desired result set, the engine returns the result set. Even if you could times from the underlying operations the 'fetch' time of a query is a pretty loose concept, given that a row can suffer several transofrmations during execution, can be spooled, read multiple times, etc etc.

Comment: @Remus: Thanks for the comment. But can you explain why SQL prefers to evaluate parameters of a table valued function for each row processed inside the function (as given in the question in my comment above) ?

Comment: 'evaluate for each row processed inside a function' is a procedural statement in which you expect a certain execution path and order.

Answer (score 0):

GETDATE() (and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) return the timestamp of the start of the transaction

Comment: I tried this: BEGIN TRANSACTION; SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; EXECUTE LongRunningProc; SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- and got different results for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Here's another post that references the docs which backs up this claim: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: @odigity well, that's the behavior prescribed by SQL, whereas the question is about SQL Server which is to SQL as bastard is to star.

Comment: That had not occurred to us, dude.

Answer (score 0):

SqlServer is performing a the GETDATE() at first and then replaces the value trough all the rows.

Comment: Then can you answer why [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819513/big-performance-difference-1hr-to-1-minute-found-in-sql-can-you-explain-why] is happening?